# Flutter Sqlite Error: Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such table: employees (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Tags: sqlite, flutter, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

I am trying to create and insert data in `sqlite` database. While calling insert query the error displayed that is "no such table: employees"(see attached image), I can understand there is no table created. But I have code to create a table. Actually `onCreate()` not triggered while opening database in initialization step. Help me to resolve this issue.

Code:

```
class DBHelper {
  DBHelper._();
  static final DBHelper db = DBHelper._();

  static Database _database;

  static Future<Database> getDBConnector() async {
    debugPrint("creating connection...");
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    }

    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  static Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    debugPrint("intialize database...");
    _database =
        await openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'employee_info.db'),
            onCreate: (db, version) {
      debugPrint("creating employees table...");
      return db.execute(
        '''CREATE TABLE employees(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, age INTEGER,address LONGTEXT)''',
      );
    }, version: 1);

    return _database;
  }

  static Future<void> saveEmployee(Employee employee) async {
    final Database db = await getDBConnector();
    await db.insert("employees", employee.toMap(),
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
  }

  static Future<List<Employee>> getEmployees() async {
    final Database db = await getDBConnector();

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps =
        await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FFROM employees");

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Employee(
          employeeId: maps[i]['id'],
          employeeName: maps[i]['name'],
          age: maps[i]['age'],
          address: maps[i]['address']);
    });
  }
}
```

[image: screen shot of error]

Comment: Seems like you cannot create a table in app at first start and run app without created table. First of all, you can try to remove app from device/emulator and install it again, because `onCreate()` method in Database creation calling if database not exists.

Comment: yes its working, i have uninstalled and clean the build files now its working. thank u